# How can I have a protected scope inside a JS application which in no way can get affected by any other function?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function that accepts another function as a parameter.
Is it possible for the outer function to run the inner function without knowing what it does and avoid any changes it tries to make to any variable in the protected scope.

Note: By protected, I am not referring to the protected inheritance scope specifier available in Java,C++ or C#.

**Example:**

Suppose I have a function processor.

```
{
 // processor is a function of an object which has input and output be parameters
function processor(functionToExecute)
{
  this.output = functionToExecute(this.input);
}

}
```

Now I don't know what code, does functionToExecute will run.

I have few variables a,b or c at global scope.
I dont want them to be affected or any other function at global scope to be called from functionToBeExecuted.
I just want it to accept parameters and give the output.

but should not be able to have a side effect that affects anything outside its scope.

Ideally I will be asking this function as from the user and run it on the server to process a piece of data as the user wants.

Comment: The function that you pass in already has a different scope, you wouldn't be doing any changes to the outer function...Could you post some code, maybe I'm not getting the idea...

Comment: What do you mean by protected?

Comment: Now check. I have added an example and my intention.

Comment: The keyword you're looking for is [sandboxing](https://www.google.com/search?q=nodejs+sandboxing)

Answer (score 1):

The scope of a function is determined at the time it is declared, not when it is executed.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
var b = 3;

function foo(fn){

  //JS is function-scoped. It's the only way you can create a new scope.
  //This is a new scope. It cannot be accessed from the outside
  var a = 4;
  var b = 5;
  var b = 6;

  //We call the passed function. Unless we pass it some references from this scope
  //the function can never touch anything inside this scope
  fn('hello world');
}

foo(function(hw,obj){

  //the function passed is defined here where, one scope out, is the global scope
  //which is also where a, b and c are defined. I can *see* them, thus they are
  //modifiable
  console.log(a,b,c); //123
  a = 7;
  b = 8;
  c = 9;
  console.log(a,b,c); //789

  console.log(hw); //hello world

});
```

Also, globals are visible *anywhere* in the code. Any code *can* modify globals, except for some cases, like WebWorkers but that's another story.

Here's an example of how to use an immediate function to hide values, and only expose functions to use them:

```
(function(ns){

  var width = 320;
  var height = 240;

  ns.getArea = function(fn){
    fn.call(null,320 * 240);
  }

}(this.ns = this.ns || {}));

//let's get the area
ns.getArea(function(area){
  console.log(area);
});

//In this example, we have no way to modify width and height since it lives inside
//a scope that we can't access. It's modifiable only from within the scope
//or using a "setter" approach like in classical OOP
```

But for objects, they are passed by reference. Once you pass them somewhere, they *can* possibly be modified.

Comment: So, If I have a list of Json Objects. I want to accept a function from the user and then I want to run that function as a map  on the entire list and display the user a new list on the client a an effect of his code.
How do i achieve this making sure, user doesn't write anything that affects anything else other than the list items ?

Comment: @AmoghTalpallikar put your stuff in a scope that can't be reached by the arbitrary code. I suggest you read how to emulate private scopes in JS to learn more about protecting values.